Error CS8370: La caracteristica 'Directiva global de uso' no esta disponible en C# 7.3. Use la versión 10.0 del lenguaje o una posterior
Tengo un proyecto sin documentación en C# que presenta el error CS8370 y las diferentes soluciones que vi por foros no funcionan
No sirve remover
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

de los archivos csproj ni forzar el dotnet build de los archivos bin y obj especificando la versión del lenguaje

El mismo mensaje indica el problema, debes configurar como minimo la versiòn 10 del SDK .NET CSharp, puedes realizarlo en tu archivo de proyecto .csproj  en <LangVersion>:
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

